# Slow motion video software program for linux

Tags: linux, video

I'm using ubuntu 14.04 ubuntu 64bit and I'm looking for a slow motion software package like **slowmoVideo** http://www.webupd8.org/2014/02/create-classy-slow-motion-videos-in.html  I tried installing slowmoVideo but it doesn't have an installable  version for 14.04 ubuntu.  Are there any other software packages that can do the same thing.

My goal is to take 1080p video of moving water and slow it down and play it smoothly so I can see how it flows.

> **Note the PPA does not work for Ubuntu 14.04 64bit** this is the error
>
> Failed to fetch
>   W: http://ppa.launchpad.net/brousselle/slowmovideo/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages
>   404  Not Found
>
> W: Failed to fetch
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/brousselle/slowmovideo/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages
>   404  Not Found